# MYSQL duplicate key syntax using multiple primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql-server, awk

Hello everyone this is my first post, so please be forgiving.

I have searched SO for these questions and while they come close to an answer what I have seen has not been correct.

#### Environment info:

- MySQL Server version: 5.1.69-community-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- Kernel version: CentOS release 5.10 (Final)

I am working on a project to track file versions within a package update. This data is currently stored in a text file in the following format.

filename version

examples (no these are not our files, just random things i thought of)

```
explorer 1.1.2.254
spoon 1.0.0.8
```

I am using a awk script to create mysql script to insert into the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL_Versions` (
  `File` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Version` varchar(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
  `LastUpdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`File`,`Version`)
);
```

Currently I am using the following insert format:

> INSERT INTO TBL_Versions (File,Version,LastUpdate) values("explorer", "1.1.2.254", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Version=VALUES(Version);
>
> INSERT INTO TBL_Versions (File,Version,LastUpdate) values("spoon", "1.0.0.8", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Version=VALUES(Version);

This leaves me with the following data in my table:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| File     | Version   | LastUpdate          |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| explorer | 1.1.2.254 | 2014-03-04 08:40:08 |
| spoon    | 1.0.0.8   | 2014-03-04 08:40:23 |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Later the versions file may be updated to say the version of spoon is 1.0.0.10, but the version of explorer will NOT have changed. So in the file it would look like this:

```
explorer 1.1.2.254
spoon 1.0.0.10
```

Is there a way to have the awk script write the insert to allow it to change spoon but not explorer? I am open to changing the table if needed or anything else that might be required. Your more experienced minds may already see the issues that I am having but I will lay out what I need to happen.

```
1. I want the line for explorer to remain unchanged.
2. I want the Version and LastUpdate for spoon to change.
```

Thank you to everyone in the community in advance for the assistance. It is very appreciated.

Comment: Your keys are File,Version. So on DUPLICATE your File and Version are exactly as those you want to insert. Updating the Version should not make sense then, right?

Comment: You key is a combination of File and Version... or on Duplicate Key would work only if the combination of File and Version is duplicate... Just one won't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

With your current table schema, a combination of the File and Version uniquely identifies a record...if only the File is the Primary key and you remove the Unique Key attribute from Version, you can try REPLACE into TBL .. instead of INSERT into TBl.

mysql> REPLACE INTO TBL_Versions (File,Version,LastUpdate) values("explorer", "1
.1.2.256", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

This can be a simpler query .. provided ..the PRIMARY KEY constraint is only on the File column..

Comment: Why? Why replace instead of insert? What are the differences? What might happen if one uses that?

Comment: REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Comment: And if there was a FK constraint to that pk that just got deleted?

Comment: If the version of the File keeps on changing in the table... I am not sure if it is a good candidate for being a FK.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.

Change to the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL_Versions` (
    `File` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `Version` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `LastUpdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`File`)
);
```

I then wrote a bash script to read from a file as described

Create update file from version file.

```
awk '{ printf "INSERT INTO TBL_Versions (File,Version,LastUpdate) values(\"%s\", \"%s\", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Version=VALUES(Version);\n", $1, $2 }' $VerFile | sed -e"s~\"~\'~g" > /tmp/versions.$$
```

Then I pipe the /tmp/versions.$$ file to mysql.

```
cat /tmp/versions.$$ | while read Update
do
mysql -u$USER -p$PASS DATABASE -Nse "$Update"
done
```

All of that is within a larger shell script. Has been running live for a while and working without a hitch. It is called as a cron job nightly.